# ( ndb, python, gae) - cron job timeout using more than one module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Is there something special that I need to do when working with cron jobs for separated modules? I can't figure out why I can make a request to the cron job at localhost:8083/tasks/crontask (localhost:8083 runs the workers module), which is supposed to just print a simple line, and it doesn't print to the console, although it says that the request was successful if I run it by going to http://localhost:8000/cron and hitting the run button.. but even that still doesn't hit make it print to the console.

If I refresh the page localhost:8083/tasks/crontask as a way of triggering the cron job, it times out.

again, If I go to localhost:8001 and hit the run button, it says request to /tasks/crontask was successful, but it doesn't print to the console like it's supposed to

**In send_notifications_handler.py within in workers/handlers directory**

```
class CronTaskHandler(BaseApiHandler):

    def get(self):

        print "hello, this is a cron job"
```

**in cron.yaml outside the workers module**

```
cron: 

- description: something

  url: /tasks/crontask

  schedule: every 1 minutes

  target: workers
```

**in init.py in the workers/handlers directory**

```
from send_notifications_handler import CronTaskHandler

#--- Packaging



__all__ = [

    CounterWorker,

    DeleteGamesCronHandler,

    CelebrityCountsCronTaskHandler,

    QuestionTypeCountsCronHandler,

    CronTaskHandler

]
```

**in workers/routes.py**

```
 Route('/tasks/crontask', handlers.CronTaskHandler, methods=['GET']),
```

//++++++++++++++++++++ Updates / resolution +++++++++++++

1. The print statement is fine and does print to the console
2. Yes, the cron job will fire once under the using the dev server, although it doesn't repeat
3. The problem was that _ah/start in that module was routed to a pull queue that never stops. removing the pull queue fixed the issue.

Comment: using print will typically return the printed value to the requester as a response and not print to the console. You should use logging if you want things to appear on the console.

Comment: weird.. print statements always print to the console when they are fired in handlers.. i've been doing it for months.. and I know I've done a simple cron job that did print to the console like this, the only difference is that now I'm using separate modules.. it seems to be running on the default module instead of the worker module

Answer (score 0):

That is actually the expected behavior when **executing cron jobs locally**.

If you take a look to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Cron_support_in_the_development_server), it says the following:

> The development server doesn't automatically run your cron jobs. You can use your local desktop's cron or scheduled tasks interface to trigger the URLs of your jobs with curl or a similar tool.

You will need to manually execute cron jobs on local server by visiting http://localhost:8000/cron, as you mentioned in your post.

Comment: lol, yeah, that's exactly why this comment doesn't help much ;). I did 'manually execute cron jobs on local server by visiting http://localhost:8000/cron' and it still didn't print.. I also hit the link directly in the browser. Just because it doesn't keep running doesn't mean that it shouldn't execute even once

Answer (score 0):

/++++++++++++++++++++ Updates / resolution +++++++++++++

1. The print statement is fine and does print to the console
2. Yes, the cron job will fire once when using the dev server, although it doesn't repeat, which is normal behavior for dev servers
3. The problem was that _ah/start in that module was routed to a pull queue that never stops. removing the pull queue fixed the issue.
4. Thanks for suggestions